# specify another directory to compgen for auto completing directories, than using pwd

Tags: bash, bash-completion, compgen

`compgen -d -- $cur` will suggest completions for the directories in pwd only right?

Can I get it to suggest directory completions for some dir while being in another dir.

For eg. if I am in `/curr_dir`, and I want to generate directory completions for `/other_dir` what do I do? How do I specify it to `compgen`, so that I don't need to go to `/other_dir`

In my bash-completion function, I tried doing a `cd` to that dir before calling `compgen` but that leaves me in the other dir after pressing `<Tab>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `compgen -d -- $cur` will suggest completions for the directories in pwd only right?

No, it will complete `$cur`, assuming the content is a path. Try it yourself by entering the
command directly into your shell. Example:

```
$ compgen -d -- "/"
/run
/lib64
/usr
[...]
```

So the only thing you have to do is to use "$other_dir" instead of "$cur".
Also, remember to quote the strings or the shell might split the directory name:

```
compgen -d -- "$foo" # good
compgen -d -- $foo   # bad
```